# Why aren't congressmen/women arrested for interrupting State of the Union

Tags: united-states

Reports are mentioning that a [heckler was arrested for shouting during the State of the Union](https://www.militarytimes.com/news/pentagon-congress/2024/03/08/father-of-marine-killed-in-afghanistan-arrested-at-state-of-the-union/). I understand it's a relatively small charge, misdemeanor, but what rules/laws are in place that stop any Congresspersons from the same arrest?  Marjorie Taylor Greene, for example, interrupted/heckled during the speech as well but was not arrested.

I assume there's some sort of protection for the Congresspeople, but am having trouble finding anything specific online.

Comment: I read that Seargeant at Arms threatened to remove her for wearing a hat but I'm guessing someone decided that wasn't worth the drama.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Speech and Debate Clause provides absolute immunity for members of Congress for anything that they say in the Capitol from anyone other than Congress itself, which can fine and otherwise punish its members, expelling them by a two-thirds majority if it deems fit.

Article I, Section 6, Clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution states:

> The Senators and Representatives shall receive a Compensation for
> their Services, to be ascertained by Law, and paid out of the Treasury
> of the United States. **They shall in all Cases, except Treason,
> Felony and Breach of the Peace, be privileged from Arrest during their
> Attendance at the Session of their respective Houses, and in going to
> and returning from the same; and for any Speech or Debate in either
> House, they shall not be questioned in any other Place.**

Anyone else can be arrested by Capitol Police or other suitable officials.

Comment: Incidentally, Congress did expel a member, George Santos, for the first time in twenty years and the third in more than 150 years. He still has permission to enter the House floor, and attended the State of the Union.

Comment: @Davislor But since he's not actually a Representative any more, he could have been arrested if he misbehaved.

Comment: @Barmar Arrested for what? He wasn’t trespassing. Is there any law against heckling the President? Presumably the Sergeant-at-Arms could have asked him to leave.

Comment: @Davislor "Is there any law against heckling the President?" In the middle of the State of the Union speech, yes, it's probably disturbing the peace or disorderly conduct. A pretty minor misdemeanor, but almost surely a crime.

Comment: @Davislor Or if he refused to leave....

Comment: But why wouldn't heckling fall under the "Breach of the Peace" exception in that clause?

Comment: @user168715 heckling someone is not a Breach of the Peace according to the DOJ. A Breach of the Peace is defined as behavior that could lead to physical conflict. Where that line is... is fuzzy. But it is somewhere between speaking and fisticuffs (though I would pay good money to see a bout of fisti cuffs erupt in congress/the senate)

Comment: @Questor It wouldn't be unprecedented, of course.

Comment: @ohwilleke It would not... Though with the average senator closer to being a centenarian then not I think someone collapsing from a heart attack is far more likely.

Comment: @Questor - In the blue corner we have Kamala Harris, and in the red corner... the crazy queen of conspiracy MARJORY TAILOR GREEEEEEEEEN... ngl, I'd pay to watch that

Answer (score 41):

The State of the Union takes place in Congress, and is a function of Congress (not the Executive, who is an *invited guest*).

In Congress all members have privilege. They could conceivably call for parliamentary procedures such as a "Point of Inquiry" or a "Personal Privilege" or even "Suggest the Absence of a Quorum" or "Make a Motion". As such, interrupting and yelling is just a member speaking out of order, without being recognized by the chair.

The members of the general public, however, have NO privilege at all, and are informed on entry by posted signs that they are expected to be silent or be removed.